# How to chain a JS function with d3.transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a bar chart with d3, that pulls bar sizes from the array.
So I am trying to animate shifting between adjacent bars with a function swapper, which works, but only once. Bars are swapping places on the first call but would ignore the second call. I think that the problem is that second call to the function is executed before first transition is finished. How do i make second call to wait for the first one to finish?

```
const data = utils.generateRandomArray(25,45);
const width = "500px";
const height = "300px";

const graph1 = d3.select("#graph1").append("svg")
                  .attr("height", height)
                  .attr("width", width)
                  .attr("style", "border: 1px solid black");

utils.renderGraph(graph1, data);
utils.renderGraph(graph2, data);

const bar1 = graph1.select(".bar-1");
const bar2 = graph1.select(".bar-2");
const bar3 = graph1.select(".bar-3");
const bar4 = graph1.select(".bar-4");

    function swapper(bar1,bar2){
        bar1.transition()
            .delay(1000)
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("x", `${bar2.attr("x")}`);
            
        bar2.transition()
            .delay(1000)
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("x", `${bar1.attr("x")}`);
    }
    
    swapper(bar1,bar2);
    swapper(bar1,bar2);
```

Comment: You can add a name to your transitions to stop them from stepping on each other - bar1.transition("firstone") and bar2.transition("secondone")

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`.end()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_end)

> Returns a promise that resolves when every selected element finishes transitioning. If any element’s transition is cancelled or interrupted, the promise rejects.

So perhaps something like

```
async function swapper(bar1,bar2){
    const bar1Transition = bar1.transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("x", `${bar2.attr("x")}`);
        
    const bar2Transition = bar2.transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("x", `${bar1.attr("x")}`);

    return Promise.all([bar1Transition.end(), bar2Transition.end()]);
}

swapper(bar1,bar2).then( () => {
  return swapper(bar1,bar2);
});
```

Comment: It did actually work, with a little tweak - async had to be before function (It did work without async keyword as well) and .end() to Promise.all(like in previous comment) or adding .end() directly to transitions inside function.
   I also made it work by returning bar2Transition.end() ,since both transitions perform in same time.
   Thank you, guys, for helping me out.